# What are the differences between console and PC versions?

Tags: world-of-tanks

Are there any differences in mechanics between World Of Tanks in console compared to its PC version?

Answer (score 1):

Updates will be much more frequent on the PC than Xbox 360.

For example wargaming are going through all the tanks overhauling their textures and have made several big changes to maps recently.

In order for these kind of updates to be applied to the xbox version, each one would need to pass a number of certification tests.

This was the problem with the console version of Team Fortress 2 and as a consequence the Pc and console version became so different you could no longer compare them.

The console version does have controller support which is a nice thing that the PC does not have.

With the PC version you can install mods and customise how you HUD looks and display live stats to help you when playing the game.